# Trying to Schedule two processes at same time

Tags: blueprism

I want to schedule two processes one after other after completion of first process the second process has to start.Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

The Blue Prism Scheduler can do just what you describe. First, open the Control tab, right-click on Schedules, and select `New Schedule`:

[image: Blue Prism Schedules contextual menu]

After configuring all the information on the next screen, you can then set up individual tasks (right click the new schedule and select `New Task`) in the Scheduler and configure one process to run after the other by setting the task's `On Complete` property properly.

[image: Blue Prism Example Task #1]

[image: Blue Prism Example Task #2]

This topic is covered extensively in Blue Prism official documentation. On the client portal, look for the "Blue Prism - Guide to the Scheduler" document.